# Delete 2 column headers and shift the whole column row to left in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Delete 2 column headers and shift the whole column row to left in dataframe. Below is my dataframe.

```
    trash1  trash2  name    age
0   john    54      
1   mike    34      
2   suz 56      
3   tin 78      
4   yan 31
```

i need the final df as below

```
    name    age
0   john    54      
1   mike    34      
2   suz 56      
3   tin 78      
4   yan 31
```

I tried all the commands but its deleting the whole column. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slice with [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and rename with [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html):

```
N = 2
out = (df.iloc[:, :-N]
         .set_axis(df.columns[N:], axis=1)
      )
```

Output:

```
   name  age
0  john   54
1  mike   34
2   suz   56
3   tin   78
4   yan   31
```

##### Timing of answers for a generalized number of columns:

Overall manually setting the name is reliably the fastest since the data is fully untouched, independently of the number of columns. The nice `pop` trick becomes very greedy after a threshold. Some of the approaches like `shift`+`drop` additionally cause the DataFrame to become fragmented

[image]

Comment: This is interesting data, especially that bend at ~100 columns. What was the length of your test df? Can you share your benchmarking code?

Comment: @Nick [here it is](https://pastebin.com/5aaipyJd). I had to use a try/except for Laurent's code as it was triggering random errors (in place modification?)

Comment: Error comes from your modification in my code, the use of `modulo`. The calculation of `N = df.shape[1]//2` does not take into account commas, it always truncates downwards. If the number of columns is odd, this can cause problems. Should I deduce that my calculation is the fastest? :-p

Comment: @LaurentB. no I always used even numbers in the test for simplicity, so `df.shape[1]//2` is always correct (btw `//` is floor division, not modulo which is `%`).

Comment: right for `modulo`. there is another problem : inplace modification

Comment: @LaurentB. yes this is trickier to test. In the end your solution is a bit similar to mine, except you're performing copies of the data and removal of columns (which is slow) where I only slice and rename (which is fast). This is the opposite logic (keep headers/move data vs keep data/move headers)

Comment: I agree that your solution is elegant. I like the ticket tips. I doubt there is a better solution among the others because it depends on the structure of the data (one could see it by strange movements on the curves). But on ticket trick, I should admit it may be the fastest

Comment: @mozway thanks for the code. `perfplot` now running on my computer. :) found another interesting solution (which also has the strange bend around 100 but not to the same extent) `df.drop(columns=df.columns[N:]).rename(columns={o:n for o, n in zip(df.columns[:N], df.columns[N:])})`

Answer (score 3):

**Code**

```
out = df.shift(2, axis=1).drop(['trash1', 'trash2'], axis=1)
```

out

```
    name    age
0   john    54
1   mike    34
2   suz     56
3   tin     78
4   yan     31
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'trash1': ['john', 'mike', 'suz', 'tin', 'yan'], 
         'trash2': [54, 34, 56, 78, 31], 
         'name': None, 'age': None}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Comment: This is the slowest of the posted answers - see my answer for benchmarking

Answer (score 2):

Another solution :

```py
# Copy
df[['name', 'age']] = df[['trash1', 'trash2']]
# And drop
df = df.drop(['trash1', 'trash2'], axis=1)
```

```
   name  age
0  john   54
1  mike   34
2   suz   56
3   tin   78
4   yan   31
```

Comment: If you're interested, see my answer for benchmarking results.

Comment: Thanks for your invitation. It is difficult to decide on the most efficient method. This depends on several parameters including the data structure, the number of rows and columns, etc.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution using [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) to transfer the column data:

```py
df = df.assign(name=df.pop('trash1'), age=df.pop('trash2'))
```

Output:

```
   name  age
0  john   54
1  mike   34
2   suz   56
3   tin   78
4   yan   31
```

I ran timings on all the answers (including Corralien's comment below this answer) using a dataframe of 1M rows and this benchmarking code:

```py
timeit(setup='''
import pandas as pd
import random
random.seed('shift')
N = 1_000_000
df = pd.DataFrame({'trash1' : random.choices([f'word{i}' for i in range(N)], k=N), 'trash2':random.choices(range(N), k=N), 'name' : None, 'age' : None })
''', stmt='''
out = df.shift(2, axis=1).drop(['trash1', 'trash2'], axis=1)
''', number=1)
```

with the `out =`  line changed as appropriate. The results show this method to be almost 2x faster than anything else:

| Method | time |
| --- | --- |
| Nick | 0.029 |
| mozway | 0.047 |
| Laurent B. | 0.077 |
| Panda Kim | 0.126 |
| Corralien | 0.227 |

Comment: Not sure how efficient though ;)

Comment: If `name` and `age` are nan, you can also use `df.fillna({'name': df.pop('trash1'), 'age': df.pop('trash2')})`

Comment: @mozway presumably they're not doing this all the time... otherwise I think they need another question! :)

Comment: @Nick I meant that performance with pop should become pretty bad when generalizing to more columns. I'll add a comparison in my answer